# How can I build Victorian Style windows?

Tags: building

How can I build Lego Victorian style windows, like those on the White House or Capital Building?

This is one style I have done, which, as far as I know, was an original idea by me:
[image]

Comment: What size do you want?

Comment: Similar to the size I have in the picture.

Comment: You may want to include close-up pictures of the real windows too if you can find some.

Comment: The White House and Capital are technically both [palladium architecture.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palladian_architecture#North_American_Palladianism)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This Flickr user's model evokes nice victorian windows without using any glass

http://www.flickr.com/photos/lgorlando/3914963760/

as does this one

http://www.flickr.com/photos/lgorlando/4099206027/

See also this amazing series on window techniques

http://www.flickr.com/photos/28192677@N06/5713290533/in/set-72157626335716516/

which includes this beaut

[image: Windows - Court House in Karlstad, Sweden]

Also consider these stained glass designs. Stained glass is VERY victorian, although not the way you meant :)

http://www.brothers-brick.com/2010/12/04/christmas-window/

[image: Several stained glass designs, from Flickr]

Comment: I like the last one in particular, I think it very well suits the style the OP was looking for.

Comment: It's now second to last as I moved the stained glass example to the bottom.

Comment: Welcome Larry, good to see you here!